# Int is not subscriptable

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a password system is python but when I tried to compere the user password to the right password I get an exception

```
'int' object is not subscriptable
```

```
import time

user_pass = input("Enter password here: ")
if len(user_pass) == 4:
 print("u entered the correct amount of numbers!"), time.sleep(0.5)
else:
 print("wrong password!")
 exit()

for i in user_pass:
    if not i.isdigit():
    print("u must enter numbers only! \"{}\" is not a number!!!!!!!".format(i))
    exit()

password = 1234

if (user_pass[0]) == str(password[0]):
    print("the first number is correct")
else:
   print("the first number is wrong!")
   exit()
```

Comment: `password = 1234` should be `password = "1234"`

Comment: `str(password)[0]` will fix it

Comment: Also avoir single line multiple instructions (`print(), time.sleep()`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things here;

Firstly you need to indent your `if not i.isdigit()` block:

```
if not i.isdigit():
    print("u must enter numbers only! \"{}\" is not a number!!!!!!!".format(i))
    exit()
```

You will probably get an exception otherwise.

For your issue; it looks like you are setting the value of `password = 1234` which is a integer. You can set this to `password="1234"` or `str(password)[0]`.

Answer (score 0):

the error occurs because in the line `(user_pass[0]) == str(password[0])` you are trying to take the first character in an integer value, you can do  this only with strings, so to fix your problem you should modify this `(user_pass[0]) == str(password[0])` to this: `str(user_pass)[0] == str(password)[0]`

so the script should look like this:

```py
import time

user_pass = input("Enter password here: ")
if len(user_pass) == 4:
    print("u entered the correct amount of numbers!")
    time.sleep(0.5)
else:
    print("wrong password!")
    exit()

for i in user_pass:
    if not i.isdigit():
        print("u must enter numbers only! \"{}\" is not a number!!!!!!!".format(i))
        exit()

password = 1234

if str(user_pass)[0] == str(password)[0]:
    print("the first number is correct")
else:
   print("the first number is wrong!")
   exit()
```

Answer (score 0):

I've tested your code and formatted it again. there was some minor issue regarding indent and string casting, check this out

```
import time

user_pass = input("Enter password here: ")
if len(user_pass) == 4:
 print("u entered the correct amount of numbers!"), time.sleep(0.5)
else:
 print("wrong password!")
 exit()

for i in user_pass:
    if not i.isdigit():
    print("u must enter numbers only! \"{}\" is not a number!!!!!!!".format(i))
    exit()

password = "1234"

if (user_pass[0]) == password):
    print("the first number is correct")
else:
   print("the first number is wrong!")
   exit()
```